# Visual Studio Debugging

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed windows 7 64 bit I cannot debug an app in Visual studio using the Cassini web server. I have attempted to use firefox, chrome and IE and nothing will let me connect in debug mode. As anyone seen this issue before? All make it appear as though the website does just not exist.

EDIT:

I cant even  get a aspx page to display after the Cassini web server has been spun up by visual studio. Is simply wont connect, I have read this could have something to do with IPV6?

Comment: Do you have a web.config file?  Is debugging enabled in the web.config?

Comment: Do you see anything in the Event log that might indicate something has failed?

Answer (score 1):

Edit and Continue does not work when Visual Studio is running on a 64-bit Windows operating system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241066%28VS.80%29.aspx

You can however perform remote debugging.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184678%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: That is edit and continue, I cant even get a aspx page to display after the Cassini web server has been spun up by visual studio